# Codenameone creating printable documents

Tags: android, ios, mobile, printing, codenameone

In my codenameone app (ios/android) i want the user to be able to print out what is rendered on the screen. This could be tabular information or maybe a certificate of their achievement. 
But what options are open to me get that screen content onto A4 paper?

FYI to generate the formatted screen, the app will have received the JSON data from a Dropbox MySQL database, and then formatted as normal.

From reading this forum, **I know that direct print is not a feature of apps**, so my next route is to use the ShareButton object in CN1 and get the user to basically export the screen content to a 3rd party app, which can print. But this is limited to text strings or photos (not both) and so a tabular screen would not export correctly. I also expect that doing this from an iPhone to the Mail app would not be fit for A4 size.

The mobile browser does this very well by being able to export to the PDR reader but that PDR reader isn't an option when exporting from apps.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Share allow sharing both text and an image as far as I know so this should work. Generally the most common approach I've seen is to generate a PDF on the server and then use `Display.execute()` to run the PDF file which launches the OS native viewer.

I know some folks did some work on print integration based on questions asked here and in the forum but I don't know if they succeeded. There is nothing contributed back as far as I know.

Comment: I'll take a look at the server PDF generation route. Thanks for the swift reply.